# test significance between models with emmeans

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, emmeans

Let's say I have these two models

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x=factor(c(1,2,1,1,2,2)),y=c(2,5,2,1,7,9))
dat2 <- data.frame(x=factor(c(1,2,1,1,2,2)),y=c(3,3,4,3,4,2))

mod1 <- lm(y~x,data=dat1)
mod2 <- lm(y~x, data=dat2)
```

and calculate a t test between the levels of `x` in each model

```
t1 <- pairs(emmeans(mod1, ~x))
t2 <- pairs(emmeans(mod2, ~x))
```

How can I assess whether the two models are significantly different for this contrast using emmeans?

Comment: I can’t think of a way. Moreover, emmeans is used to summarize one model. It is not designed for comparing models. Generally, people use some kind of anova for that. In this case, you’d need models involving the combined datasets: one that fits the same model to all the data, and the other has additional parameters that account for differences between the datasets, via a factor that designates which dataset and interactions of that factor with other predictors.

Comment: Thanks rvl. I see. I thought I could simply use the t values and some measure of dispersion from both models to compute some meaningful statistic (like when calculating effect sizes). You are saying there's not a way to do this even if using another library?

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat1$dataset <- "dat1"
dat2$dataset <- "dat2"
alldat <- rbind(dat1, dat2)
modsame <- lm(y ~ x, data = alldat)
moddiff <- lm(y ~ x * dataset, data = alldat)
anova(modsame, moddiff)
```

Don't try to use `emmeans()` to do this; that isn't its purpose. The `anova()` call above compares the two models: `modsame` presumes that the `x` effects are the same in each dataset; `moddiff` adds two terms, `dataset` which accounts for the change in overall mean, and `x:dataset` which accounts for the change in `x` effects.

The comparison between the two models comprises a joint test of *both* the `dataset` and the `x:dataset` effects -- it is an *F* test with 2 numerator d.f. -- not a *t* test.